# Remove Sitecore Publishing Warnings

Tags: sitecore

When a Sitecore user opens an item which is not in a final state of a workflow, on top of the "Quick Info" area on a yellow background it says

```
If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it is not in the final workflow step.
```

Is there a way I can avoid this happening for Items which are in certain workflow states.

Comment: I guess that if you mark all your "certain workflow states" as final the warning will go away. Otherwise, I don't recommend hiding it (even if there's the way to do it)

Comment: The thing is we need some processing to do before transferring them to final states. Items which are in these states would be automatically transferred to final states by Sitecore agents. But for a admin user it is confusing to see the message that these will not be published even though they are going to get published eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that generates this warning sits in the `<getContentEditorWarnings>` pipeline. While I agree with Yan; Just because you can, doesn't mean you should - this would be where you need to go. I am not sure which of the processors in there generate your specific warning, but you can go digging with Reflector or just plain comment them out one by one until it goes away.

More likely you will want to code a specific step here, to generate a warning in line with the business rules you describe.

Pipeline looks like this (in Sitecore 7)

```xml
<getContentEditorWarnings>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.ItemNotFound, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanReadLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.HasNoVersions, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanWrite, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanWriteWorkflow, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.CanWriteLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.IsReadOnly, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.IsLocked, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.HasNoFields, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.NeverPublish, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.ItemPublishingRestricted, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.VersionPublishingRestricted, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.ShowingInputBoxes, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.FeedIsEmpty, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.RunRules, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.Notifications, Sitecore.Kernel" />
</getContentEditorWarnings>
```

You can find a post by John West on how to code new warnings for this pipeline [here](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/11/content-editor-warning-to-display-publishing-status.aspx).

Comment: It is VersionPublishingRestricted class.